# JQuery Mobile don't show progress bar when page load via Ajax

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm building an app utilizing JQuery Mobile in which I'm showing a progress bar to indicate to the user their progress based on the steps completed.

For the progress bar I'm utilizing JQuery UI which is simple to implement

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){     

        var currentStep = $("#formNumber").val(); //get the the current step from form  
    var totalSteps = 8;
    var formProgress = 0;

        // determine overall form progress after step is completed  
    if (currentStep >1) {         
        formProgress = (currentStep-1)/totalSteps*100;
        }   

    // Set progress value
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({value: formProgress});
    $('#percentage').text(formProgress);

   });// End function

</script>
```

However since the pages in JQuery Mobile are loaded via Ajax the progress bar does not show. I'm guessing it's because the "#progressbar" div is empty.

if the pages loads without Ajax it will show the progress bar. Any one knows how i can solve this by allowing the progress bar to show when the page loads via Ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bind to pageinit not dom ready](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html) or in this case i bind to pageshow. In a JQM ajax app dom ready only happens once on the first page. So any new content brought into the dom doesn't get the benefit of the code you wrote. Also when the second page is brought into the dom. The first page doesn't go anywhere its just hidden. Because of this using the same id in every page causes problems. Get used to using classes instead. If you need to pick something out of the current page use the .ui-page-active class to help you select the appropriate element.

Something like `$('.ui-page-active .formNumber')` will select the correct input for you. So here is my revised first step according to the info you gave me.

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Step 1</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getProgress(){
                var currentStep = $(".ui-page-active .formNumber").val(); //get the the current step from form  
                var totalSteps = 4;
                var formProgress = 0;

                // determine overall form progress after step is completed  
                if (currentStep >1) {         
                    formProgress = (currentStep-1)/totalSteps*100;
                }
                $(".ui-page-active .progressbar").progressbar({value: formProgress});
            }

            $(document).on('pageshow',function(){
                getProgress();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="step1">

            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Step 1</h1>
            </div><!-- /header -->

            <div data-role="content">
                <input type="hidden" class="formNumber" value="1" />
                <div class="progressbar"></div>
                <a href="step2.html" data-role="button">Step 2</a>        
            </div><!-- /content -->

        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

> step2.html

```
<div data-role="page" id="step2">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Step 2</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <input type="hidden" class="formNumber" value="2" />
        <div class="progressbar"></div>
        <a href="step3.html" data-role="button">Step 3</a>        
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div>
```

> step3.html

```
<div data-role="page" id="step3">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Step 3</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <input type="hidden" class="formNumber" value="3" />
        <div class="progressbar"></div>         
        <a href="step4.html" data-role="button">Step 4</a>        
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div>
```

...... and on and so forth

If you interested I made a sample for you to look at. http://starwebservices.net/so/

Comment: Thanks for the response @codaniel however the id or class is not the issue as I'm not utilizing Jquery moible single page option as you indicated above. I'm utilizing the Multi-page option The progress bar works fine on all pages but only if the page is not loaded via Ajax  . was just wondering if anybody knew of a workaround

Comment: I know but its still the same issue even with separate pages. You cannot have two different divs with the same id. Even though you can't see the first page it is still in the dom.

Comment: Thanks once again I tried it, converted the id to class still the same issue if the page is load via Jquery Mobile AJAX the progress bar still doesn't show but shows if the page is loaded without it. The progress bar <div> is actually in a footer not on each individual page. The footer however is include as a general file when each page is loaded

Comment: Show your code if you can because it works fine on my local host. I tried it with multiple page layout and single page layouts.

Comment: Here is the Jquery   $(document).ready(function(){var currentStep = $("#formNumber").val(); //get the the current step var totalSteps = 8;
 var formProgress = 0;
 // determine form progress  
 if (currentStep >1) {    
  formProgress = (currentStep-1)/totalSteps*100;
  } 
 
 $("#progressbar").progressbar({value: formProgress});
 $('#percentage').text(formProgress);});// End function <div id="progressbar"></div>